# I want to set the Control Type of a variable to "UserControlObject" in WorkWithPlus

Tags: genexus, workwithplus

I want to set the variable Control Type to the "UserControlObject" I created, why is it not in the list with WorkWithPlus properties?

Will it appear on the list with the versionup of WorkWithPlus?

Control Type of variable can be changed from WebForm.

I need the same list as Genexus WebForm properties.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the properties you have available, but maybe if you can define the domain on which the variable is based on, you can set the control type properties in the domain itself, instead of the WWPlus pattern instance.

Comment: The UC you created, ¿has the property "Is control Type" in TRUE? An option is to use an UserTable, then on the web form you can drag the variable manually and the Control Type of your UC should appear: https://docs.workwithplus.com/com.wiki.wiki?583,User+Table,

Comment: @Fede Thanks for your comment. It is possible to change the Control Type in the Domain, but I cannot change the properties of the UserControl.

Comment: @GuidoLorenzatti Thanks for your comment. Currently, using UserTable may be the best method.